# How to use a windows/web service to alert user about an event?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-services, webforms

Here I am trying to create an alert system and I have some stored data(date/time) in one of my data table. I just want to send an e mail alert to user when current date/time equals to the stored time. Someone please explain me a way to do this.
Thanks in advance...!

Comment: Windows service is the good option for this

Answer (score 0):

If all the data is stored in SQL Server Database, you can use Jobs. Example:
[How to create a scheduled job in SQL server 2008 via T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15391936/how-to-create-a-scheduled-job-in-sql-server-2008-via-t-sql)