# How to create a scheduled job in SQL server 2008 via T-SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, jobs, schedule

I want to create a job which deletes records from a database after a period of time has passed. For example I have a field in news table `Time Stamp` and each month a SQL query runs like a scheduled job against my database and deletes news where the time stamp is two month old. Generally I want to delete news for 2 month ago and older to not let my table become a large table. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you should [create a job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx) in SQL 
below is a sample T-SQL for create a job via SQL agent

```
USE msdb ;
GO
EXEC dbo.sp_add_job
    @job_name = N'Weekly Sales Data Backup' ;
GO
EXEC sp_add_jobstep
    @job_name = N'Weekly Sales Data Backup',
    @step_name = N'Set database to read only',
    @subsystem = N'TSQL',
    @command = N'ALTER DATABASE SALES SET READ_ONLY', 
    @retry_attempts = 5,
    @retry_interval = 5 ;
GO
EXEC dbo.sp_add_schedule
    @schedule_name = N'RunOnce',
    @freq_type = 1,
    @active_start_time = 233000 ;
USE msdb ;
GO
EXEC sp_attach_schedule
   @job_name = N'Weekly Sales Data Backup',
   @schedule_name = N'RunOnce';
GO
EXEC dbo.sp_add_jobserver
    @job_name = N'Weekly Sales Data Backup';
GO
```

Comment: What is the purpose of N in `=N'...'`

Comment: @xyz The N in front of a text value indicates that the following text is of type nvarchar instead of varchar.

For the difference between those two data types, see here:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144283/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-nvarchar)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a [SQL Agent Job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135739%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to schedule a job to periodically run. If you want to create the job with T-SQL, refer to [How to: Create a SQL Server Agent Job (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181153%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).